# Mapping with Automapper and Underscores

Tags: c#, automapper

In the below example, I'm just trying to get Test_Person_Name.FirstName to map to something (anything) in TestPersonFlattened. At this point, considering the amount of time I've sunk into this, I'm not too hung up on what the destination property name is..I just want it to work.

```
public class Test_Person
{
    public Test_Person_Name Test_Person_PublicName { get; set; }
}

public class Test_Person_Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class TestPersonFlattened
{
    public string Test_Person_PublicNameFirstName { get; set; } // What do I call this property?
}

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Test_Person, TestPersonFlattened>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

It seems like Test_Person_PublicNameFirstName should work, but I get an exception on AssertConfigurationIsValid(). I've also tried TestPersonPublicNameFirstName, Test_Person_PublicName_FirstName as destination property names.

It'd be unfavorable to rename the source property name, just because the source library is used in many other projects. Also, a ForMember() call isn't ideal, but I'll do it if there's no other option.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to simply leave out "Test_Person_" from the `PublicNameFirstName` property of your `TestPersonFlattened` class, and use `RecognizePrefixes()` to make it so that AutoMapper ignores "Test_Person_" when attempting to map property names.

The following code succeeds:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Test_Person_");
            cfg.CreateMap<Test_Person, TestPersonFlattened>();
        }); 
        Mapper.CreateMap<Test_Person, TestPersonFlattened>();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
public class Test_Person
{
    public Test_Person_Name Test_Person_PublicName { get; set; }
}

public class Test_Person_Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class TestPersonFlattened
{
    public string PublicNameFirstName { get; set; } // This is what I call this property!
}
```